# ASP.NET grid with auto-paging,sortable,searchable... GridView? ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I need to build a `<table>` to display Products. I am not very familiar with GridView or ListView, not sure if they can do these below.

The requirements:

- Automatic paging. Fetch only 100 records at a time (not the whole 1000000 records when it first loads)
- Sortable. I need to be able to specify the default sort order, but user can also click on the header
- Searchable. User needs to be able to filter the data they want to see.
- I (the programmer) need to be able to easily turn off/on columns (Ideally I only need to comment out one line to hide a column)
- Data will be from SQL Server, multiple tables

Does anyone know any ASP.NET control that can do all the above? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `GridView` and `ListView` can do paging if you put a `DataPager` in them. `ListView` is a templated control - the display is completely customised so you have to roll your own "columns"; don't have much use for `GridView` so I don't know about that one.

As for searching and sorting, there's some sort of builtin support for it that becomes useless if you need a data source ASP.NET can't query directly - an `ObjectDataSource` lets you create your own data access code, but you also have to implement everything that can't be done automatically.

For searching, you can handle the ODS's `Selecting` event, you can pass arbitrary parameters to the query method; I believe there's also some way to automagically get control values / query string parameters etc.

For sorting, `ListView` lets you add `Button`s where `CommandName="Sort"` and `CommandArgument="[column to sort by]"`. When using a non-custom data source, I believe they will Just Work. When using an `ObjectDataSource`, all they do is make the `ListView` keep track of a "sort expression" that you can pass into your data source in the `ODS.Selecting` event. The format of the sort expression is specified… somewhere I can never find when I need it. When using single-column sorting, this will be either `"[column name]"` for an ascending sort, or `"[column name] DESC"` for a descending one. You can pass this directly to `ObjectQuery.OrderBy`; `EntityFramework.Extended` also provides that extension method for the new API surface. `ListView` (I believe) only handles single column sorting, for multiple-column sorting you have to manage the sort expression yourself anyway.

The documentation for all this is scattered, a good starting point is [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/displaying-data-with-the-objectdatasource-cs), its followups, and the links for `ListView` you can find in the sidebar to the left.

My project also has a reasonably simple use of a `ListView` in combination with an `ObjectDataSource` – meaning, no part of it relies on magic RAD features, that follows below. I extracted it from my actual project, so it might have minor inconsistencies.

## `ListView`+`ObjectDataSource` Example

The following example retrieves "messages" (think news announcements on a company portal) from a WCF service (not included).

### MessagesDataSource.cs

An `ObjectDataSource` delegate that calls a WCF service. The data source is responsible for:

- **filtering** based on the `username` and `type` parameters
- **sorting** based on the *sort expression* in the `sort` parameter
- **paging** as specified by the `skip` and `take` parameters - named to be consistent with [the LINQ operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336757)

Because we're using an `ObjectDataSource`, all of this has be implemented in the delegate – this is where the service is ultimately called.

```
public enum MessageType
{
    None = 0,
    All,
    General,
    OfficeHoursUpdate,
    // …
}

[DataObject]
public class MessagesDataSource : IDisposable
{
    IMessagesService _svc = new MessagesServiceClient();

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public IEnumerable<Message> Select(string username, MessageType type, string sort, int skip, int take)
    {
        return _svc.GetMessages(username, type, sort, skip, take);

    }

    public int SelectCount(string username, MessageType type, string sort, int skip, int take)
    {
        return _svc.CountMessages(username, type);
    }
}
```

### Messages.ascx

Renders a list of messages as a table with one `<tbody>` per message, with one row split into columns for the message "headers", and a second row with all columns merged for the message body. Points to note:

- When a value is selected in the dropdown list, the `ListView` is refreshed starting with the first page.
- All the parameters the `MessageDataSource.Select()` and `.SelectCount()` methods take should be declared in the ODS's `<SelectParameters>`. (Visual Studio will show an error if they don't match.)
- The `TypeName` attribute of the ObjectDataSource control indicates the ODS delegate that gets instantiated by the ODS. For more control over this, handle the `ObjectCreating` / `ObjectCreated` events of the ODS. (For instance, you can pass the containing control to the ODS delegate.)
- The values for the parameters named by the `StartRowIndexParameterName` and `MaximumRowsParameterName` attributes will be provided automatically by the data pager.
- I don't believe the value for the `SortParameterName` parameter is filled in by the `ListView` when using an `ObjectDataSource` - it might or might not be when using a `GridView`. I also don't think it's necessary in this case but then again it's not hurting anybody to keep it there.
- I omitted the data pager fields, they're just clutter here.
- The `CommandArgument` values of the sorting `LinkButton`s in the header don't have to match up the properties of the data objects and can in fact be completely arbitrary.

```aspx
<asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddlType" Text="Message Type:"/>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlType" AutoPostBack="true" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged"
                  OnLoad="ddlType_Load" />
<table>
  <asp:ListView ID="lvMessages" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsMessages" ItemPlaceholderID="message">
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='Timestamp' 
                            CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Timestamp" />
            <asp:Literal ID="lvMessages__Timestamp" runat="server" 
                         OnPreRender="UpdateSortIndicator" />
          </th>
          <th>
            Sender
          </th>
          <th>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='Subject'
                            CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Subject" />
            <asp:Literal ID="lvMessages__Subject" runat="server" 
                         OnPreRender="UpdateSortIndicator" />
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <asp:DataPager ID="dpMessages" runat="server" 
                           PageSize="10" PagedControlID="lvMessages"
                           OnInit="dpMessages_Init">
              <Fields>
                <%-- Data Pager Fields --%>
              </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <%-- 
          The following tag gets replaced with the rendered contents of 
          ItemTemplate for each data item
      --%>
      <tbody runat="server" id="message" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%# Eval("Timestamp") %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%# Eval("Sender") %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%# Eval("Subject") %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <%# Eval("Body") %> 
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
      No messages loaded!
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
</table>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsMessages" runat="server" TypeName="Foo.MessagesDataSource"
  DataObjectTypeName="Foo.Message" SelectMethod="Select"
  SelectCountMethod="SelectCount" StartRowIndexParameterName="skip" MaximumRowsParameterName="take"
  OnSelecting="dsMessages_Selecting" EnablePaging="true" SortParameterName="sort">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="username" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="scope" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="sort" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="skip" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="take" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

### Messages.ascx.cs

This class is reasonably straightforward and deals mostly with initialising the page and tangential issues like sort indicators. Most of the "interesting" bits have had comments added to them.

```
public partial class Messages : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Initialise the dropdown list values
            var types = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MessageType));
            types.Remove(MessageType.None);
            foreach (var t in types)
            {
                ddlType.Items.Add(new ListItem(t.ToString()));
            }

            // Default message filter and sort
            Type = MessageType.All;
            lvMessages.Sort("Timestamp", SortDirection.Descending);
        }
    }

    private MessageType _type;
    public MessageType Type
    {
        get { return _type; }

        set
        {
            if (!_type.Equals(value))
            {
                ddlType.SelectedValue = value.ToString();
                _type = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private static readonly IDictionary<SortDirection, string> SortIndicators =
        new Dictionary<SortDirection, string>
            {
                {SortDirection.Ascending, "\u25b4"}, // upwards triangle
                {SortDirection.Descending, "\u25be"} // downwards triangle
            };

    /// This is where you can programmatically add / change the values of
    /// parameters that will get passed to MessagesDataSource.Select()
    protected void dsMessages_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add "filter" parameters that have to be determined programmatically.
        e.InputParameters["username"] = GetUsernameLoggedIn();
        e.InputParameters["type"] = Type;
    }

    /// When the message type changes, go back to the first page
    protected void ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Type = (MessageType) ddlType.SelectedValue);
        var pager = (DataPager)lvMessages.FindControl("dpMessages");
        if (pager == null)
        {
            ((IPageableItemContainer)lvMessages).SetPageProperties(0, 10, true);
        }
        else
        {
            pager.SetPageProperties(0, pager.PageSize, true);
        }
    }

    /// Reload the value from the dropdown list.
    protected void ddlType_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Type = (MessageType) ddlType.SelectedValue;
    }

    protected void UpdateSortIndicator(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var indicator = (Literal) sender;
        if (indicator.ID.EndsWith("__"+ lvMessages.SortExpression))
        {
            indicator.Text = SortIndicators[lvMessages.SortDirection];
        } 
        else
        {
            indicator.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I don't claim to be an authority on the topic and am in fact fairly new to .NET. This just happens to be something I had to deal with recently and was also confused by the scattered documentation that tended to either take shortcuts with a part of the problem (i.e. either use GridView to get a complete view automatically, or use an ADO.NET data source instead of custom data access code); or spend too much space on fluff (e.g. screenshots of what button to click in which Visual Studio wizard.)

Comment: The OP needs to implement custom paging without writing any code.  The GridView/ListView out of the box needs custom paging code to handle 1000000 rows.

Comment: @Alison: If you need a nontrivial data source, one that ASP.NET can't query directly, you have to write some code, and that's the case my example covers. If the OP can make do with the data sources that support automatic database-side paging, this is well covered in the documentation I linked to, and I assume should Just Work. I think ListView and GridView might have some sort of builtin paging when working over in-memory data; I'll go out on a limb and assume that's not particularly useful to anyone, so that's not covered.

Comment: Thank you Sii for your very thorough answer! :)

Comment: @aximili No problem. Just be aware that if all you need is a data table, GridView (or third party grid components) can probably give you sorting headers, sort indicators, and hiding columns "for free", and are probably worth looking into. Same for paging, sorting, and (maybe) filtering if you can use LinqDataSource, SqlDataSource, and such.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free but Telerik's RadGrid is incredibly full-featured and either does 100% of what you need or else it will get you pretty darn close.

Telerik RadGrid: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if your data is going to be just displayed only not edited or updated you can go with a `Data Repeater` control. It is a very light weight control but then you may have write all the logic for the paging and sorting.It is good in a way so that you get fine grained control over your code..

Check this link for more details.[ASP.net Repeater Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx#S7)

Comment: Thanks Ashley. Isn't GridView better than Repeater in this case? But I'll look at it, thanks.

Comment: @aximii... Grid view is a pretty heavy control compared to Repeater.If you are looking for a quick solution go for gridview or even better Listview .but if you feel you may need to do lot of customizations in future repeater is a better choice..

Comment: I downvoted the answer because a) the OP specifically mentions requirements that have to be done completely from scratch when using a Repeater; b) these are requirements that GridView+[noncustom data source] implements out of the box; c) ListView+DataPager+ObjectDataSource give you sufficiently fine-grained control over anyway, except they still correctly track paging/sorting state for you across postbacks. I feel your answer recommended pretty much the exact opposite of what the OP asked for with no tangible upside.